# Proper Case formatting a text in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way to create a "proper case text display in JasperReports".  I am using JasperReports 5.x with iReport Designer.

I have data returned from DB which is a string/text field user entered text... the problem here is some users enter in all calitals and some enter in all small I want to display the text values in a proper case... I know this can be achieved in SQL but unfortunately I dont have that option to simply edit the query....

Thanks for your help in advance...

Meeza

Answer (score 0):

There wouldnt be any standard settings in iReport, you would need to use an external Method to create the text you need. I would try to go for an Apache Commons solution, or create your own Method.

I have not used the [WordUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), but it looks like capitalize may be what you want. 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)

To Add a Jar to your classpath in iReport:

```
Tools -> Option -> Classpath -> Add Jar
```

You then need to import the Class as well:

```
From the Report root element, edit the Properties.  Find "Imports" click on the ellipses (...) and add your class!
```

[iReport Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myCls.png)